# JAVA SQLite: Error Bad Request Field

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having problem in Storing my Searched data to my list. Could anyone check my construction of my storing array and array list. Thanks.

`Tag CursorWinow: bad request for field slot 0,12. numRows = 49, numColumns =12`

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getAllDataFromTable(String tableName) {//, String[] ColumnList
        List<HashMap<String, String>> TableDataCollection;
        TableDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +tableName;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        String ColumnCollection[];

        int totalRecord=cursor.getColumnCount();
        if(tableName=="tbl_account_codes")
        {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
              int i=cursor.getColumnNames().length;
              ColumnCollection=new String[i];

              String MainColumnCollection[];
              MainColumnCollection=new String[i];
             String[] MyColumn= ColumnCollection=cursor.getColumnNames();//column
              for(int a=0;a<=i;a++) 
              {

                  MainColumnCollection[a]=(cursor.getString(a).toString());//= ColumnCollection[a]
                  String z="wala lang";
                  String x="wala lang";

                  //String AssignCol= MyColumn[a];
              }

               TableDataCollection.add((HashMap<String, String>) Arrays.asList(MainColumnCollection));
               String c="wala lang";
              } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return TableDataCollection;
            }
TableDataCollection.add((HashMap<String, String>) Arrays.asList(MainColumnCollection));
```

I'm having problem at this line. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following line

```
MainColumnCollection[a]=(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME")));
```

instead of

```
MainColumnCollection[a]=(cursor.getString(a).toString());
```

**EDIT**

remove `=` from your `for` loop and change like this

```
for(int a=0;a<i;a++)
```

Comment: i dont want to indicate my string column name sir, that's why i used a for loop for indexing the item... because i want to process all of my table search with this class function..

Comment: Thanks it worked. and i'm not having the right output. i need to display it to an array list..

Comment: Yes sir I accepted ur answer. Thanks for your help, the condition of the for-loop is crucial.